# How can I access the audio output coming from a movie playing in processing?

Tags: audio, processing, movie, minim

I am working on a film analysis program, which retrieves data in realtime from a movie, that is playing in the same sketch. For analysing the sound I tried the minim library, but I can't figure out, how to get the audio signal from the movie. All I could do was accessing an audio file, I was loading into the sketch manually, or the line-in through the mic.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although GStreamer (used by the processing-video library) has [access to audio](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/2012.5/gst-plugins-base-plugins-0.10/gst-plugins-base-plugins-playbin2.html#GstPlayBin2--audio-sink), the processing-video library itself doesn't expose that at the moment.

You will need to use workarounds at the moment:

1. Extract audio from your movie and load straight into minim. (you can trigger audio playback at the same time as movie playback if you need to)
2. or use a tool to use system audio output as an input (minim get line in). On OSX you can use [Soundflower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/). Another option is [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/) and it's patch interface.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried Soundflower and with a little bit of trial and error I figured it out. Would have been great, if there was an easier way though.